# Pattern for handling MySQL database connections within an express application

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, node-mysql

I am using express 4.x, and the latest [MySQL](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) package for node.

The pattern for a PHP application (which I am most familiar with) is to have some sort of database connection common file that gets included and the connection is automatically closed upon the completion of the script. When implementing it in an express app, it might look something like this:

```
// includes and such
// ...
var db = require('./lib/db');

app.use(db({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  pass: '',
  dbname: 'testdb'
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  req.db.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (err, users) {
    res.render('home', {
      users: users
    });
  });
});
```

Excuse the lack of error handling, this is a primitive example. In any case, my `db()` function returns middleware that will connect to the database and store the connection object `req.db`, effectively giving a new object to each request. There are a few problems with this method:

- This does not scale at all; database connections (which are expensive) are going to scale linearly with fairly inexpensive requests.
- Database connections are not closed automatically and will kill the application if an uncaught error trickles up. You have to either catch it and reconnection (feels like an antipattern) or write more middleware that EVERYTHING must call pior to output to ensure the connection is closed (anti-DRY, arguably)

The next pattern I've seen is to simply open one connection as the app starts.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
connection.on('connect', function () {
  // start app.js here
});
```

Problems with this:

- Still does not scale. One connection will easily get clogged with more than just 10-20 requests on my production boxes (1gb-2gb RAM, 3.0ghz quad CPU).
- Connections will still timeout after a while, I have to provide an error handler to catch it and reconnection - very kludgy.

My question is, what kind of approach should be taken with handing database connections in an express app? It needs to scale (not infinitely, just within reason), I should not have to manually close in the route/include extra middleware for every path, and I (preferably) to not want to catch timeout errors and reopen them.

Comment: I recommend you to read about http://sequelizejs.com

Comment: Your problem may depend on what you're doing in the 'middleware' area.  On what sort of scale are you querying:  Is it many queries per second?  Are you reusing the same connection for many queries?

You may want to checkout [pooling](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections) if you are going to make many requests.


When you pool, make sure to release your connections back to the pool when you are done with them.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you're talk about MySQL in NodeJS, I have to point you to [KnexJS](http://knexjs.org/#Installation-pooling)! You'll find writing queries is much more fun. The other thing they use is connection pooling, which should solve your problem. It's using a little package called [`generic-pool-redux`](https://github.com/bookshelf/generic-pool-redux) which manages things like DB connections.

The idea is you have one place your express app access the DB through code. That code, as it turns out, is using a connection pool to share the load among connections. I initialize mine something like this:

```
var Knex = require('knex');
Knex.knex = Knex({...}); //set options for DB
```

In other files

```
var knex = require('knex').knex;
```

Now all files that could access the DB are using the same connection pool (set up once at start).

---

I'm sure there are other connection pool packages out there for Node and MySQL, but I personally recommend KnexJS if you're doing any dynamic or complex SQL queries. Good luck!

Comment: I spent a day with this error doing all sorts of trial and error fixes. Finally I understood this only when I read it the second time. I used a different variable name instead of `Knex` for ease of use.

Comment: About the implementation how to pass initialized knex instance around... Monkeypatching variable to required module is pretty nasty and may even cause problems if knex is updated. Would be cleaner to write own module, which initializes singleton instance of knex with correct configuration. Or to just pass knex instance to all parts of you app where it is needed.

Comment: Knex is not automatically exiting, so the process will remain open, what do you recommend?